# SVG support for html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, svg, html2canvas, webpage-screenshot

I was trying to capture a screenshot of a div containing svg elemens along with other elements using html2canvas. I found 2 versions of html2canvas

[Version 1](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta1/html2canvas.js)

[Version 2](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta1/html2canvas.svg.js)

Whats the difference between them, and does any of hem support svg elements and cross browser functionality (prefereably IE, Chrome and Firefox)

Answer (score 1):

buddy,  u should import

```
<script src="html2canvas.js"></script>
```

,but not necessary

```
<script src="html2canvas.svg.js"></script>
```

version1 is  rely on the vesion 2